# visual studio doesn't recognize cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have MVC 3 installed, I don't know why, but Visual Studio don't recognize me the cshtml code and I see all of the code black.

Any ideas what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: post a screenshot or something. be more specific. what does *don't recognize* mean?

Comment: I think he means that because it's "all black" VS or Intellisense isn't picking it up as code.